# a html page that take advantage of openflashchart cannot be displayed as expected

Tags: javascript, html, flash, open-flash-chart

My test.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> my title </title>
  <script> type="text/javascript" src="/openflashchart/js/swfobject.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
  <td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("/openflashchart/open-flash-chart.swf","my_chart","480","360","9.0.0","expressInstall.swf",{"data-file":"data.json"});
    </script>
    <div id="my_chart"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
...blabla
</body>
</html>
```

I place openflashchart in the home directory of apache, i.e., `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`. This html file and the json data to be loaded are placed in Documents/Data/myfiles. This page is supposed to be displayed with a curve. However, there is nothing as I visit `http://localhost/Data/myfiles/test.html`.

**Update**
Now I know that the reason is that I didn't install Adobe Flash Player, while this package is flash based. Untill now I cannot successfully install `Adobe Flash Player` on my mac. But that's  another problem.
Since `chrome` has built-in support for flash, this page can be displayed properly with it. I still has probelms with safari and firefox.